# Running QEMU with support for RISC-V Vector Extensions

Tags: clang, qemu, riscv, gnu-toolchain

I am doing research for my thesis on a topic that requires running QEMU with support for the SVE format. My issue is that I cannot figure out how to find the matching versions of the various tools required, in order to even run the official RVV `.s` samples.

I have installed the [gnu-toolchain for RISC-V](https://github.com/riscv-collab/riscv-gnu-toolchain) and installed the Linux cross-compiler, since I am running everything on an Ubuntu 22.04 Linux WSL VM.

I have also followed their instructions on building LLVM so that I can build RISC-V programs. Furthermore, I have downloaded and installed QEMU v.6.2.0 for the riscv64 architecture.

After doing lots of research on the appropriate instructions for compiling an RVV sample and running it using QEMU, (here's the [strcpy.s](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-v-spec/blob/master/example/strcpy.s) sample), I have landed on the following sequence of commands:

1. Compiling the example assembly file into an object file using:
   `riscv64-unknown-elf-as -o ~/sample.o ~/rv_strcpy.s -march=rv64gc_zve64x`
2. Generating the executable file to be loaded on QEMU using:
   `riscv64-unknown-elf-ld -o ~/sample ~/sample.o`
3. Finally, running the executable using: `qemu-riscv64 -cpu rv64,x-v=true,vlen=256,elen=64,vext_spec=0.7.1 ~/sample`

This, however, leads to an “unsupported” spec error after which, I cannot figure out a compatible spec version. After removing the `vext_spec` argument, the execution terminates with an “Illegal Instruction” error.

Does anyone have any tips on how to proceed from here? Am I missing something, am I on the right track, or am I completely lost in my workflow?

Comment: Is qemu documented as supporting this version of vext?

Comment: @NateEldredge Do you happen to know where I can find that sort of information? All i could find is that QEMU will support RISC-V foundation extensions if they are in a ratified state. If i am not mistaken, the Vector extensions are considered stable enough for v.1.0.0.